# How can I select rows of a data frames if column is a list?

Tags: r, mongodb, list, dataframe, select

I'm kinda new in R development.

I'm retrieving data from a MongoDB instance to R using mongolite. I want to retrieve all the records, so R can put them into a data frame and then iterate over it, like selecting specified rows by column value.

The problem is that one of the columns is a data frame too. See the example above. How can I access to column coordinates selecting only       *9.125, 36.125*?

I tried with:

```
df[df$location$coordinates == coords,]
```

where *coords* is

```
 [[1]]
 [1]  9.125 37.125
```

but I receive *comparison of these types is not implemented*

Where am I wrong? Type of *coords* or selecting over the data frame? Thank you.

**Input**

```
location.type ---- location.coordinates ---- value 
Point              9.125, 37.125             1   
Point              9.125, 36.125             2
Point              8.125, 37.125             3
```

**Output expected**

```
location.type ---- location.coordinates ---- value 
Point              9.125, 37.125             2
```

After 2st comment I tried

```
  coords[[1]]
```

receiving *(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'*

```
  dput(head(df))

  structure(list(location = structure(list(type = c("Point", "Point", 
  "Point"), coordinates = list(c(9.125, 
  37.125), c(9.125, 36.125), c(8.125, 37.125))), row.names = c(NA, 6L
  ), class = "data.frame"), value = 1:3))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I receive the error "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'". I will update the post.

Comment: can you provide a `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: Yes, just added in the post. Thanks

Comment: @Darkwilmore I think the expected output is first row

Comment: Yes, thank you @Clemsang, it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `%in%`:

```
df <- data.frame(location.type = rep("Point", 3))
df$location.coordinates <- list(c(9.125, 37.125), c(9.125, 36.125), c(8.125, 37.125))
df$value <- 1:3


df[df$location.coordinates %in% coords,]
  location.type location.coordinates value
1         Point        9.125, 37.125     1
```